# How to activate custom commandbar in PowerPoint 2013

Tags: c#, vsto

I want customized right click menu, Only use visual studio(VSTO).

So.. My code is

```
foreach(CommandBar cb in Application.CommandBars)
        {
            if (cb.Name.IndexOf("Shapes") > -1)
            {
                cb.Reset();
                m_oBarPopup = (CommandBarPopup)cb.Controls.Add(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlPopup, 1, missing, 1, missing);
                m_oBarPopup.Caption = "TEST";
                m_oBarPopup.BeginGroup = true;
                CommandBarButton popup_child = (CommandBarButton)m_oBarPopup.Controls.Add(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton);
                popup_child.Caption = "TEST Button";
                popup_child.Click += new _CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(clickTest);

            }                
        }
```

Code is not error. But not showing that custom menu.
How to Showing custom menu in right click menu of ppt shape?
Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may be able to find a way to do it in code, but FYI the latest approach for this uses [Ribbon XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942866.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Chris, I will try again.